# How to use java8 stream to calculate sum of values combined with a grouping by statement

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a Person class which has gender and age fields. I want to get the sum of age for each gender by below code.

```
public void test() {
        List<Person> roster = new ArrayList();

        Map<Integer, Integer> totalAgeByGender =
                roster
                        .stream()
                        .collect(
                                Collectors.groupingBy(
                                        Person::getGender,
                                        Collectors.reducing(
                                                0,
                                                Person::getAge,
                                                Double::sum)));
    }

    static class Person {

        private int gender;
        private double age;

        public int getGender() {
            return gender;
        }

        public double getAge() {
            return age;
        }
    }
}
```

I am having a compile error with above code as below:

```
Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert double to U.
```

It complains the last part of the steam statement `Double::sum`. If I change the type of age to integer and use `Integer::sum` in the above code, it works fine. I wander what wrong with the Double::sum in this case.

In addition, is it possible to group by the sex field and return `Map<Integer, List<Person>>` from one steam statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the following 2 slight problems here: (1) your identify is being interpreted as an Integer; and (2) the values of your map are Double(s).

```
Map<Integer, Double> totalAgeByGender = // not Map<Integer, Integer>
    roster.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Person::getGender,
            Collectors.reducing(
                0d, // not 0
                Person::getAge,
                Double::sum)));
```

As mentioned below, you could make this more concise and less error prone using Collectors.summingDouble:

```
Map<Integer, Double> totalAgeByGender = roster.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Person::getGender,
        Collectors.summingDouble(Person::getAge)));
```

You can group by sex (gender) easily enough:

```
Map<Integer, List<Person>> sexToPeople = roster.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Person::getGender, 
        Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: `Collectors.summingDouble(Person::getAge)` is more concise.